# Symfony 4 common data in all views - best practice

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

What are the best practices for placing common data for many views (twig), eg. main menu, bottom menu, breadcrumbs, etc.
I know that I can do it using embedded controllers, but it is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many commonly used things can be accessed by using the built in variabble [app](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/app_variable.html), ie {{ app.user }} returns the currently logged in user.

If you need something else you can write your own twig [extensions](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html).

Comment: How to add, for example, the menu which got from the database to such variable "app" ?

Comment: You might want to look at this : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

You can inject a service into all twig templates and call a function which returns data from your db

Comment: And how to cache such data got from services ?